# SwiftUI ScrollView horizontal RTL not working correctly

Tags: uiscrollview, swiftui, right-to-left, hstack

I'm trying to support RTL mode on my ios , which was built using swiftUI
every is fine while doing this to change the layour direction :

```
.environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
```

Only with  horizontal ScrollView , it's not work correctly

when i do this :

```
 ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack{
                Text("b1")
                Text("b2")
                Text("b3")
            }
        } .environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
```

Items positions will rotate , but the HSTACK will stay always on the left like the screenshot below : 
[image]

Any solution or hack to make it to the right ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I find a hack to do this using `.flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true)` and `.rotation3DEffect`

Like that the scrollview will be flipped , than you need to flip each item of HStack to `.rotation3DEffect`

```
 ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack{
                Text("b1")
                    .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: 180), axis: (x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(10), z: CGFloat(0)))
                Text("b2")
                 .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: 180), axis: (x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(10), z: CGFloat(0)))
                Text("b3")
                 .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: 180), axis: (x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(10), z: CGFloat(0)))
            }
        }.flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true)
        .environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
```

Comment: It works, but I think there has to be a better way to do it

Comment: I think `.flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true)` this would work alone. No?.. It fixed my problem

Comment: @Alhomaidhi has the write answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

By programatically scrolling (with `.scrollTo`) to trailing anchor of view in onAppear if `layoutDirection` is `.rightToLeft`, you get correct scroll position.
Works also if `layoutDirection` is `.leftToRight`

```
struct ScrollViewRTL<Content: View>: View {
    var showsIndicators: Bool
    @ViewBuilder var content: Content
    @Environment(\.layoutDirection) private var layoutDirection
        
    init(showsIndicators: Bool = true, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.showsIndicators = showsIndicators             
        self.content = content()
    }
        
    var body: some View {
       ScrollViewReader { proxy in
         ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: showsIndicators) {
             content
                 .id("RTL")
                 .onAppear {
                     if layoutDirection == .rightToLeft {
                           proxy.scrollTo("RTL", anchor: .trailing)
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
 ScrollViewRTL {
     HStack {
         Text("b1")
         Text("b2")
         Text("b3")
     }
 }
```

Comment: This works well + 1. But when content size is less than scroll view width. The bouncy effect of scrollview will be gone with this.

Answer (score 1):

A more adaptable solution based on Ouail Bellal's answer:

```
@Environment(\.layoutDirection) var direction

ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack{
            Text("b1")
                .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: direction == .rightToLeft ? 180 : 0), axis: (x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(10), z: CGFloat(0)))
            Text("b2")
             .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: direction == .rightToLeft ? 180 : 0), axis: (x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(10), z: CGFloat(0)))
            Text("b3")
             .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: direction == .rightToLeft ? 180 : 0), axis: (x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(10), z: CGFloat(0)))
        }
    }.flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true)
```

it works well in rightToLeft and leftToRight

Answer (score 1):

For versions iOS 16.4 and later, use:

```
ScrollView {
    // Your content here
}
.scrollBounceBehavior(.basedOnSize, axes: .horizontal)
```

Answer (score 0):

as a hack, you coud start with this:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geom in
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                Text("b1")
                Text("b2")
                Text("b3")
            }.environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
             .padding(.leading, geom.size.width - 100) // adjust for the number of items
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: like that , it does not scroll to the left because of the padding

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
I ask the question again for ios17 and solved. Please I examine thread ⬇️

> [Is there a way to use scrollview RTL (arabic) with LTR animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77440793/is-there-a-way-to-use-scrollview-rtl-arabic-with-ltr-animation)

We had a lot of problems with our arabic related our application, the modifier below solved our problem, don't forget to follow me on githup.

https://gist.github.com/metin-atalay/bdf28a604fe9678403730d14f02946ca

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77440793/is-there-a-way-to-use-scrollview-rtl-arabic-with-ltr-animation

Answer (score 0):

for me this code worked. Just rotate scrollview and content of scroll view too and it start to scroll from right to left and content will have right direction.

```
@Environment(\.layoutDirection) private var layoutDirection

var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 16) {
           /* content of your scroll view */
        }
        .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: layoutDirection == .rightToLeft ? -180 : 0), axis: (
            x: CGFloat(0),
            y: CGFloat(layoutDirection == .rightToLeft ? -10 : 0),
            z: CGFloat(0)))
    }
    .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: layoutDirection == .rightToLeft ? 180 : 0), axis: (
        x: CGFloat(0),
        y: CGFloat(layoutDirection == .rightToLeft ? 10 : 0),
        z: CGFloat(0)))
}
```